# PHP/MySQL - "and" followed by numerical value on form giving 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, mysql

I've ran into a little problem.

I have a form which submits data to a database. All has worked perfectly until today discovered a little bug which I can not get my head around.

If I input the word "and" followed by a numeric character (EG: "and 10") I get a 403 forbidden error saying

> You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an >ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have cleaning on the form inputs, this is the function for cleaning

```
function make_safe($variable) {
    $variable = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($variable));
    return $variable;
}
```

I've tried it with and without the cleaning.
Anyone any ideas on what may cause this error? I can't actually get anything from the error log because nothing is being put in there..

Edit:
Full code below (Please note this is a very old project which has worked for years and this bug has only just been found!)

```
<?php
checksecurity(ABSENCE_ADD);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$todate = make_safe($_POST['dateto']);
$fromdate = make_safe($_POST['datefrom']);
$reason = make_safe($_POST['reason']);
$comments = make_safe($_POST['comments']);
$date1 = str_replace("/","-",$fromdate);
$newDate1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date1));
$date2 = str_replace("/","-",$todate);
$newDate2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date2));
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$query_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_user)) {
$userid = $row['id'];
if(empty($todate) || empty($fromdate) || empty($reason)) {
    echo' You left out a field';
} else {
$query = "INSERT INTO `absences` (`id`, `fromdate`, `todate`, `reason`, `comments`, `username`, `userid` ) VALUES (NULL, '" . $newDate1 . "', '" . $newDate2 . "', '" . $reason . "', '" . $comments . "', '" . $username . "', '" . $userid . "')";
$hello = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
print $query;
                        } 

}                       
} else {
?>
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="#">
<table width="820" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="content">
  <thead>
<tr>
    <th width="820" colspan="4"><strong>Request Absence</strong></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td>From (dd/mm/yyyy)</td>
<td><input name="datefrom" class="tcal"/></td>
<td>To (dd/mm/yyyy)</td>
<td><input name="dateto" class="tcal" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Reason</td>
<td><select name="reason"> 
    <option value="Illness/Injury">Illness/Injury</option>  
    <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
    <option value="Family Engagement">Family Engagement</option>
    <option value="School or College Commitment">School or College Commitment</option>
<option value="Employment Commitment">Employment Commitment</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select> </td>
<td>Comments</td>
<td><input name="comments" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" /> <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" /> 
</form>
<?
}


?>
```

Comment: So is it right that if you don't include "and <numbers>" into your field it works? HINT: mysql is deprecated use mysqli or PDO instated!

Comment: @SebTM correct. Works fines, but I can include numbers anywhere else, it's just when they're after the 'and'

Comment: Can you provide us the full code? See my hint edited to the comment before.

Comment: @SebTM - Have edited original post; it's an old project which I haven't had time to rewrite - I will one day, just need this bug fixed which has only just been found :(

Answer (score 0):

Does your code ever emit this error message? It has exactly the same wording as the default error message returned by Apache. I suspect you are seeing an Apache error message here - in which case, the request is never getting as far as your PHP code. If that is the case, then the question is off-topic here.

The most likely cause is that you have a very overzealous WAF (mod_security?) configured which is mistaking your request for an SQL injection attack.

Comment: Nope. I never get to see the error - is there anything I could do to bypass the apache error message?

Comment: Yes, find out what part of the webserver config is triggering the error and change it.